# Strip off everything after #anchor including the #anchor

Tags: javascript, regex

Change this...

```
www.sample.com/sample.html#commentxxx?stuffhereIdontneed
```

into this...

```
www.sample.com/sample.html
```

I have it in a link so I think I need a regex?

```
document.write("<a href='"+ window.location.href.replace('?????', '') +  
"?ThisIsAppendedLater'>sample</a>");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nathan's answer is good. For completeness' sake; here's the regex:

```
var stripped = window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/,'');
```

Answer (score 7):

`window.location.hash = '';`

Comment: this beats the 'regex' tag, but it's so much nicer!  Is it portable?

Comment: I needed it in a link (I edited) but maybe it is better your way to strip it out first?

Comment: Oh ok. I would go with one of the other solutions then. It's best not to mess with the URL directly unless that's actually what you're trying to do... otherwise the browser might unexpectedly jump to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

url.substring(0,url.indexOf("#"))

Comment: +1. This is what I would use if I just wanted to retrieve the url (not modify it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex based solution, you can use:

```
window.location.href.replace('#.*', '');
```